# IPreInsertEventListener not firing for child objects

Tags: c#, nhibernate, events, orm

I've wired up `IPreInsertEventListener` and `IPreUpdateEventListener` to manage audit logging in my app, which is using NHibernate as the ORM layer.

The problem I'm having is that the `OnPreInsert()` event is fired when the object is persisted, but is not fired for each inserted child object as well.

In my case, I have a `Canine`, which has a collection of `CanineHandlers`.  What's happening is:

1. Create a new `Canine`
2. Create a new `CanineHandler` and add it to my newly created `Canine`
3. Save the `Canine`
4. `OnPreInsert` is fired with the newly created `Canine` and my `LastUpdated` & `LastUpdatedBy` fields are populated.
5. I get an error `not-null property references a null or transient value Model.CanineHandler.LastUpdatedBy`

Obviously the problem is that the `LastUpdated` fields aren't being filled in before NHibernate validates the `CanineHandler` instance, but what I can't figure out is how to get NHibernate to call the `OnPreInsert` method for each instance that's being persisted to the database.

One option that I've toyed with is adding another property to my `Auditable` POCOs that contains a group of `Auditable` child objects, but technically speaking I could save a `CanineHandler` with a modified `Canine` parent that has been changed, and then I'd be cascading the insert/update in the opposite direction.

So, am I on the right track with some incorrect code somewhere, or should I be approaching this a different way.

Here's the relevant (truncated) code:

### Auditable interface

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    int? LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    string AuditTypeName { get; }
    Object AuditGetNew(String changes);
}
```

### OnPreInsert event handler (implements IPreInsertEventListener interface)

```
public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent insertEvent)
{
    if (insertEvent.Entity is IAuditable)
    {
        IAuditable auditablePoco = insertEvent.Entity as IAuditable;
        auditablePoco.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        auditablePoco.LastUpdatedBy = (int?)PersonID;
        //Taken directly from Ayende's blog, these calls update the
        //event's state to match the entity's state
        Set(insertEvent.Persister, insertEvent.State, "LastUpdated", auditablePoco.LastUpdated);
        Set(insertEvent.Persister, insertEvent.State, "LastUpdatedBy", auditablePoco.LastUpdatedBy);
    }
    return false;
}
```

### Canine mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping namespace="CanineApp.Model" assembly="CanineApp.Model" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Canine" table="Canine">
    <id name="CanineID" type="Int32">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" type="String" length="64" not-null="true" />
    <property name="LastUpdated" type="Date" />
    <property name="LastUpdatedBy" type="Int32" />
    <set name="CanineHandlers" table="CanineHandler" inverse="true" 
        order-by="EffectiveDate desc" cascade="save-update"
        access="field.camelcase-underscore">
      <key column="CanineID" />
      <one-to-many class="CanineHandler" />
    </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### CanineHandler mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping namespace="OPS.CanineApp.Model" assembly="OPS.CanineApp.Model" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="CanineHandler" table="CanineHandler" schema="dbo">
    <id name="CanineHandlerID" type="Int32">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="HandlerPersonID" type="Int64" precision="19" not-null="true" />
    <property name="EffectiveDate" type="DateTime" precision="16" not-null="true" />
    <property name="LastUpdated" type="Date" not-null="true" />
    <property name="LastUpdatedBy" type="Int32" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="Canine" class="Canine" column="CanineID" not-null="true" access="field.camelcase-underscore" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: It was suggested that I look into the set of collection event listeners (IPreCollectionRecreateEventListener, etc.) but so far they don't seem to be what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this will work, but I noticed that your Canine mappings for LastUpdatedBy and LastUpdated are not the same as for CanineHandler. Perhaps try removing the not-null="true" from CanineHandler mappings.

I have done auditing for nHibernate in the same fashion and it worked fine, although I used  the older intercepting interface, namely IInterceptor. Also I did not have not-null="true" in my mappings.

### CanineHandler mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping namespace="OPS.CanineApp.Model" assembly="OPS.CanineApp.Model" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="CanineHandler" table="CanineHandler" schema="dbo">
    <id name="CanineHandlerID" type="Int32">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="HandlerPersonID" type="Int64" precision="19" not-null="true" />
    <property name="EffectiveDate" type="DateTime" precision="16" not-null="true" />
    <property name="LastUpdated" type="Date"  />
    <property name="LastUpdatedBy" type="Int32"  />
    <many-to-one name="Canine" class="Canine" column="CanineID" not-null="true" access="field.camelcase-underscore" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: This works.  I'd still love to see the event model spelled out somewhere, since this problem seems to have come from a mis-understanding on my part of when the OnPreInsert event fires in the pipeline.